# Несколько условий

Tags: php, условия

Привет! Ситуация в следующем, хочу сделать красиво условие а получается  какой то говнокод)

```
if(условие1){
    $xml= simplexml_load_file('link');
  if($xml){
     действие1
  }else{
     действие2
  }
}else{
   действие2
}
```

Возможно есть способ не прописывать два одинаковых действия в ветке else?

P.S. Вторым условием в моем случае является загрузка некоторых данных со стороннего сервиса, это условие должно проверяться только когда выполнено первое условие, для того что бы не нагружать сторонние сервисы постоянными запросами

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сразу положить значение в переменную `$xml` и проверить ее значение:

```
if(условие1 && ($xml= simplexml_load_file('link'))){
   действие1
}else{
   действие2
}
```

Еще можно посмотреть на, многими не любимый, оператор [goto](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.goto.php)

Answer (score 0):

Изначально:

```
if (условие1 && условие2) {
  действие1
} else {
  действие2
}
```

С уточнением вопроса:

```
if (условие1 && simplexml_load_file('link')) {
  действие1
} else {
  действие2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, самый простой вариант -

```
if (условие1 && условие2)
      действие1
else действие2
```

Comment: в вашем случае проверяются оба условия одновременно, мне же нужно по порядку, поправил вопрос

Comment: @user193361 и в чём же разница?.. Вы проверьте)

Comment: @user193361 http://ideone.com/7D1HPJ ловите

Comment: @user193361 в текущей формулировке вопроса ответ полностью подходит под задаваемые условия

Comment: еще конкретнее вопрос поправил

Answer (score 0):

Пропробуйте вот так вот...

```
if (!условие1) {
  действие2
}

$xml= simplexml_load_file('link');
if (!$xml) {
     действие2
}

действие1
```